# Bringing (impure) legacy functions in scope of Symfony controllers

Tags: php, symfony, scope, legacy-code

### The legacy project

I am rewriting a legacy PHP application to use Symfony. The former has at its core around 400 functions in `lib` that all live in global scope. The project structure looks (in a very simplified manner) like:

```
├── index.php
├── lib
│   ├── lib_foo.php
│   ├── lib_bar.php
│   └── functions.php
└── config
    └── config.php
```

All functions are presently included into the files where they are used by a single include of `lib/functions.php` which in turn includes all the other files in `lib`.

```php
# index.php
<?php
include_once("lib/functions.php");

echo greeting();
echo visitorCount();
```

```php
# lib/functions.php
<?php
include_once("../config/config.php");
include_once("lib_foo.php");
include_once("lib_bar.php");
...
// a lot more includes to follow

$db_handle = mysqli_connect(
    $config["db_host"], 
    $config["db_user"], 
    $config["db_pass"]
);
```

The functions in `lib` are not pure though, but do access a global configuration array `$config` (defined in `config/config.php`) and a shared database connection `$db_handle` (defined in `functions.php`).

```php
# lib/lib_foo.php
<?php

function greeting() 
{
    // We are reading from a global config array here
    global $config;

    return "Welcome to " . $config["sitename"];
}


function visitorCount() 
{
    // We are using a global database handle defined in functions.php here
    global $db_handle;

    return mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT `visitor_count` FROM `visitors`");    
}
```

In the new Symfony application pretty much everything is getting rewritten except for the functions in `lib` (too much effort at the moment...). These functions need to be made accessible to the new Symfony controllers. 
Since the old application is simultaneously extended, one goal is to reuse the code in `lib` with as few modifications as possible.

### What I tried/want

So how do I bring the functions into scope in Symfony? I was initially trying to:

- specify the respective files in the `files` attribute in `composer.json`
- create a Symfony Service `OldFunctionsService`, include the files in its constructor and then dependency-inject the service into the controllers where I need the old functions in scope.

However, both methods don't work for  functions that use the global `$config` and `$db_handle` variables. They only bring both variables in the function scope of the respective import function/constructor and not in global scope/scope of the controller functions from which the old functions are ultimately called.

So what are my options to bring the old functions into scope without using a (rather ugly and unflexible)

```php
require_once("config/config.php");
require_once("lib/functions.php");
```

in every controller? This also seems to have the drawback of always creating new database connection which is not what I want.

I guess `$config` could be refactored to a class with static properties and `$db_handle` to a class with a static method `getConnection` that would always return the same connection object (singleton) but that would require to change quite a bit of code in the legacy application which is not ideal...

Any thoughts?

Comment: It should probably be worth to make the functions that depends on `$config` and `$db_handle` work with environment variables and then use the `files` attribute to load the legacy code. But I don't see why global variables wouldn't work in that case ?

Comment: Well, rewriting `$config` to `$GLOBALS["config"]`, etc. would work I guess. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding the problem but I think you are making this more complicated than it really is.  A Symfony app has two main entry points: public/index.php and bin/console.  All you really need to do is to include your functions.php in those two files

```
# bin/console
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

if (false === in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg', 'embed'], true)) {
    echo 'Warning: The console should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the '.\PHP_SAPI.' SAPI'.\PHP_EOL;
}

set_time_limit(0);

require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
require dirname(__DIR__).'/lib/functions.php'; // *** Just add this
```

I made a simple command just to check:

```
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:hello';

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln(greeting());
    }
}
```

All seems to work as expected.  The greeting function is defined in lib/greeting.php and uses the global $config.  functions.php loads config.php and greeting.php.

Comment: Thank you! That is certainly a possibility I somehow didn't think of. What concerns me a bit is the (possibly not negligible) overhead of bringing the functions into scope regardless of what controller is eventually called (of course that's also the case when using the `files` attribute of `composer.json`). There will be a lot of requests to the application (mostly CRUD over REST endpoints) that don't need the old functions at all. So selectively dependency-injecting the importer seemed like a good idea at first. But maybe reading/parsing 500KB more PHP code is nothing to be concerned of...

Comment: php 7 does a really good job of caching this sort of stuff.  I would not worry about it till profiling showed it was a real problem.  If it is really only specific controllers that need access to these function then I personally don't see a problem with just including the functions file when they are needed.  Be kind of nice if php supported function autoloading but it does not.  You would have to wrap things in static class functions which is probably more trouble than it is worth.